# Laravel - Redirection if connected

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, redirect

I am a young French developer and I am at a dead end about redirections under Laravel.

I have user tables, namely Client(users) and Employes (admin) and I can log on without problem with a login form that sends me to 2 different pages:

```
 Connected as a client-> mon-compte,
 Logged in as an employe-> gestion-admin.
```

However, if I am logged in as a client and I change the url mon-compte by gestion-admin, I have access to this page and vice versa ...

So I set guards and middlewares under Laravel that seem to work but that alternately I will say. In my web.php, I have 2 groups:

```
Route::group([
'middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Employe',
], function () {
    Route::get('/mon-compte', 'ControllerConnexion@accueilClient');
    Route::view('mon-compte', 'pages/mon-compte');
    Route::get('/gestion-admin', 'ControllerConnexion@redirectClient');
});

Route::group([
'middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Client',
], function () {
    Route::get('/gestion-admin', 'ControllerConnexion@accueilEmploye');
    Route::view('gestion-admin', 'pages/gestion-admin');
    Route::get('/mon-compte', 'ControllerConnexion@redirectEmploye');

});
```

In this order of position of the groups, the access used is blocked if I change the url /gestion-admin by /mon-compte if I connect as a client, I arrive directly on the gestion-page page . If I change the url and want to go to mon-compte, it sends me back to gestion-admin.

By cons, if I reverse the 2 groups of position:

```
Route::group([
'middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Client',
], function () {
    Route::get('/gestion-admin', 'ControllerConnexion@accueilEmploye');
    Route::view('gestion-admin', 'pages/gestion-admin');
    Route::get('/mon-compte', 'ControllerConnexion@redirectEmploye');

});

Route::group([
'middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Employe',
], function () {
    Route::get('/mon-compte', 'ControllerConnexion@accueilClient');
    Route::view('mon-compte', 'pages/mon-compte');
    Route::get('/gestion-admin', 'ControllerConnexion@redirectClient');
});
```

I have the opposite effect ....

I admit that I have no solution.

Comment: Great post newbie.  Well detailed.  Do you use a step-by-step debugger like xdebug?

Comment: can we see your middleware for Employe and Client?

Comment: are you doing this on localhost?  You may have a caching issue as well.

Comment: I'm on localhost, I have to search for exactly what?

Comment: `public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
   
        if (auth()->check()) {
            
            // Redirection vers la page de connexion avec message
            return redirect('/connexion')->withErrors([
                'email' => "Vous devez être connecté pour voir cette page.",
            ]);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }`

Comment: It's the same for both

Comment: In fact, I have the impression that the middleware does not work ..

Comment: If someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Think ' if(auth()->check) ' should be ' if( ! auth()->check ) '

Comment: If I use this, I can not log in anymore

Comment: public function handle($request, Closure $next)
         {
               if (!auth()->check()) {
                      return redirect('/connexion')->withErrors([
                          'email' => 'Employe, Acces interdit à cette page.',
                     ]);
                }
            return $next($request);
         }

Comment: If I try this code in the Client middleware, I can not log in anymore, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Has anyone ever had the same problem?